# Facebook login is currently unavailable

Tags: facebook-login, business-catalyst

I'm setting up a 'Login with Facebook' button and have it on a test page. http://www.digitalinkmultimedia.com/my-account

I believe I have things set up correctly for the app at developers.facebook.com.  The app says it's public and available.  I'm using Business Catalyst as the CRM, and the facebook integration appears to be correct (App ID, App Secret, etc)

When I click the login with facebook button the first time I get the message about my profile info being shared....but when I continue I get a 'Facebook login is currently unavailable'.

One thing I noticed is that when the popup first loads the FBTOKEN parameter has a number in it, then it quickly changes to FBUTOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000#*=*

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: checked your Facebook App Id ***********                                                                 
      and than  install a new build

Answer (score 72):

In the Facebook developers console for your app, please go to App Review > Permission Feature and give Advanced Access for "public_profile" and "email".

Facebook Login of the iOS app is working well without the Advanced Access setting.

Comment: This was helpful, on Android was working okay, now on iOS I had this problem and it fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: this was it for my case.

Comment: thank you ! why does facebook has to have such a complicated interface... too many ffreakin features

Answer (score 49):

If you're experiencing this now (end of 2020) it might be due to a pending "Data Checkup":

> As part of an ongoing effort to protect user data and drive long-term value for developers, Facebook has introduced an annual Data Use Checkup for app admins to certify that their API access and data use comply with Facebook Platform Terms and Developer Policies, together with all other applicable terms and policies.

Enter https://developers.facebook.com/apps and you should see your app in red color with a note that Data Checkup is due.

You'll need to spend a few minutes to fill in a simple form...

After you're done you should be good

[image]

Comment: in 2021: You have to get Advance Access to `public_profile` and `email`

Answer (score 29):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/395514758911597/fb-login/settings/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Get Advanced Access

I agree that any data I receive through public_profile will be used in accordance with the allowed usage.

[image]

download open ssl and paste in E drive create folder software--------

and extract here openssl

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME.android\debug.keystore" | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" base64

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore | D:\FbDependentSoftware\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | D:\FbDependentSoftware\bin\openssl base64

D:\FbDependentSoftware

password :- android

8Rc05yVGh4n4xVIx4lkfCYYrzrM=

[image]

[image]

Comment: Login with Facebook is successful working using this basis steps

Comment: Thanks! spent 40 minutes trying to figure out how to grant advanced permission until saw your screenshot and realized that my browser's window is too small and it just can't fit the ''Request Advanced Access" button... ‍♂️

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

Download OpenSSL from the above link

Answer (score 10):

For me @NajamUsSaqib's comment worked, tried getting advance Access for `Email` and `Public Profile` and it started working.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, it was necessary to enable the email permissions and public_profile

Comment: This solution [was already posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586173/1255289) before that comment was made.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still facing this issue. Please check in your developer account if you have a pending Data use Checkup.
Once you complete it, it should work.

Comment: This is the same as [the answer posted 8 months previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65337809/1255289).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got fixed the following way:

Site Settings>Social Integration

on the field where it says "Enter Site URL of your Facebook application" make sure you have your address as follow:

`http://www.example.com` not `http://www.example.com**/**`

Basically it will not connect to your FB App if you have a " / " after your domain.

Comment: is this after completing the "Data Usage Check" policy ?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue.

- Check the setup is done or not. If not then review all the points that need to add the data
- make sure add icons and url properly
- make sure add domain
- make sure you have ask for the permissions that you need
- add platform and hashkey for android correctly
- Most important thing you need to work in live mode

After all the above setup you will get the success

**Developers please go through with the latest doc there is a-lot of changes in doc while integrating the facebook login or graph api or instagram api's.**